# How to add an edit button in a navigation bar for a tableviewcontroller that is not the rootviewcontroller

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uinavigationbar, storyboard

I use storyboard.
I had a `UINavigationContrller` as a Initial View Controller. it had a rootViewController relationship with a `UIViewController`.
The `UiViewController` has a push segues to a `TabBarController`.
The first relashionship of the `TabBarController` is to a `TableViewController`.

i want to add an edit button to the `TableViewController`.

I tried to use this code: `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;` 
But this row is just ignored, and the navigation bar don't show the button.

I write this code too: `self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
self.navigationcontroller.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;`

The first is not ignored (the navigation bar was hidden from the first `UIViewController`) the second is ignored and the backbutton remain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to your view controller:

```
// When this view appears, add show the navigation bar and the edit button
- (void)viewDidAppear {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO; 
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

// When this view disappears, remove the editButton and hide the navigation bar
- (void)viewDidDisappear {
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that works, but this code add the editbutton and make the navigationBar visible in a view that is not the tableView, and when I reach the table the edit button disappear

Comment: I edited the code to make it disappear again when the view disappears.